# Printing/Writing each listing of JSON in separate line using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am currently working on JSON file with about 1500 listings. I would like to save each listing in separate line. My current code is giving output in the following way:

```
{"1":x ,"2":y},{"1":x ,"2":y}
```

However, I want to save them like the following without comma and on separate line:

```
{"1":x ,"2":y}
{"1":x ,"2":y}
```

My code is as follows:

```
#this is appending my filtered data into results (running in loop for 1500 listings)
filtered_result.append(filtered_data)   

#this is dumping results into my output file
filtered_result_json = json.dumps(filtered_result, output_file) 

#this is writing results into a JSON file
output_file.write(filtered_result_json) 

#closing output file
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
filtered_result.append(filtered_data)   

for json_element in filtered_result:
   output_file.write(json.dumps(json_element))
   output_file('\n') 

output_file.close()
```